Odoo 17 using many2many to select all employee
I want using many2many fields to select all employee in my own custom module called racing teams. Every employee will have different tier in their own team.
Model
class RacingTeams (models.Model):
_name = "racing.teams"
_description = "Helpdesk Teams"
_rec_name = 'name'

name = fields.Char(string="Name", tracking=True)
desc = fields.Char(string="Description", tracking=True)
employee_ids = fields.Many2many(
    comodel_name='hr.employee',
    relation='hr_teams_rel',
    column1='name',
    column2='employee_id',
    string='Employee',
)

XML
<notebook>
   <page string="Team Member" name="team_member">
       <field name="employee_ids" required="1">
          <tree editable="top">
               <field name="name"/>
               <field name="tier_id"/>                           
          </tree>
        </field>
   </page>
</notebook>

Model HR Inherit
class HelpdeskHR (models.Model):
_inherit = "hr.employee"

name = fields.Char(string="Employee Name", related='resource_id.name', store=True, readonly=False, tracking=False)
tier_id = fields.Many2one('helpdesk.tier',string="Tier", ondelete='cascade')

but my issue right now if I add employee in new team, tier_id will show from the last team. How to make employee have different tier if I add in other team?


The unique relationship between a team, an employee, and their
corresponding tier must be captured by an intermediary model in order
to guarantee that each employee can have a unique tier in various
racing teams.Try the solution below.

Model - Racing Member:
class RacingTeamMember(models.Model):
    _name = 'racing.team.member'
    _description = 'Racing Team Member'

    team_id = fields.Many2one('racing.teams', string="Team", required=True, ondelete='cascade')
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee", required=True)
    tier_id = fields.Many2one('helpdesk.tier', string="Tier", ondelete='cascade')

Model - Racing Team:
class RacingTeams(models.Model):
    _name = "racing.team"
    _description = "Racing Teams"
    _rec_name = 'name'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", tracking=True)
    desc = fields.Char(string="Description", tracking=True)
    team_member_ids = fields.One2many('racing.team.member', 'team_id', string="Team Members")

XML View:
<notebook>
   <page string="Team Members" name="team_members">
       <field name="team_member_ids">
          <tree editable="top">
               <field name="employee_id"/>
               <field name="tier_id"/>
          </tree>
        </field>
   </page>
</notebook>

By using a One2many field that connects to an intermediary model (racing.team.member), each relationship between a team and an employee can have unique properties. For example, an employee can be assigned as a "Tier 1" in one team and "Tier 2" in another. This structure is flexible, letting you manage multiple attributes within the relationship and ensuring data integrity without redundancies or data conflicts between teams.
